# How can I see the SQL sent to the database after the parameters have replaced their placeholders?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, .net-1.0

The first MessageBox.Show() below simply shows me the exact same thing as const string SQL_GET_VENDOR_ITEMS, which seems fine to me, but I'm getting, "*There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number, Token line offset,, Token in error,,]*"

Is there a way to spy on the contents of the SQL after parameters have been added; it should then be something like: "SELECT ItemID, PackSize FROM VendorItems WHERE VendorID = 'TEST' AND VendorItemID = '852963'

Here's the pertinent code:

```
    const string SQL_GET_VENDOR_ITEMS = "SELECT ItemID, PackSize " + 
        "FROM VendorItems " +
         "WHERE VendorID = @VendorID AND VendorItemID = @VendorItemID";

    string retVal = string.Empty;
    checkConnection();
    SqlCeCommand vendorCMD = objCon.CreateCommand();
    try 
    {
        vendorCMD.CommandText = SQL_GET_VENDOR_ITEMS;
        vendorCMD.Parameters.Add("@VendorID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = VendorID; 
        vendorCMD.Parameters.Add("@VendorItemID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 19).Value = VendorItemID;

        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Made it up to vendorCMD.ExecuteReader() with sql {0}", vendorCMD.CommandText));

. . .

        vendorReader.Close();
    } 
    catch (SqlCeException sqlceex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SqlCeException in GetValsForVendorAndItem == {0}", sqlceex.Message));//TODO: Remove
    }
    finally 
    {
        vendorCMD.Dispose();
    }
    return retVal;
```

. . .

Comment: Does sql-server-ce not support parameters or something? the entire point of parameters is that they **are not** replaced. The only reason to ever "replace[d] their placeholders" would be if the database didn't support parameters. Is there any chance that `VendorID` or `VendorItemID` is `null` ?

Comment: What I mean is, the query string with the "@VendorID" needs to be replaced with some value, such as "TEST", as there is no "@VendorID" value in any of the rows. I just want to verify that the value I expect is being replaced there in my attempt to figure out what could possibly be hard to parse about the query - it seems pretty straightforward to me, and I don't know why the query parser is choking on it.

Comment: no, it doesn't need to be replaced (at least on most database engines); the parameters are sent separately to the command-text. Now it *could be* that CE does this differently, hence my question. Did you see the edit about `null` btw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I can almost guarantee that won't work in my VS2003/.NET 1.0 world

ahhh... version - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The .NET Compact Framework data provider for SQL Server CE does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement called by a SqlCeCommand when CommandType is set to **Text**. You must use the question mark (?) placeholder. For example: `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?`

Comment: Wholly crud! Thanks! This project is a sure cure for the sepia-drenched hues of moist-eyed nostalgia.

Comment: Wholly crud! And I've been showing him how to use Parameters! Doh!

Comment: Ha, ha!  Welcome back to the 90's.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on CE, your options are limited, but there are some suggestions for how to peek into the database: [Profiler for Sql CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225121/profiler-for-sql-ce)

If you were on normal SQL Server, you might consider using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx). You'd be able to see what is getting executed against the database.

Comment: If I was living in the 21st century I would, but I can almost guarantee that won't work in my VS2003/.NET 1.0 world.

Comment: @ClayShannon, this is on Database side not VS

Comment: Right, but I can't even access the database - I can't look in it, there's no way to do that (with outside tools, I mean, of course). Believe me, I've tried.

Comment: He's using SQL CE and testing on a hand held.  This isn't an option.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean that he himself is on a hand held. "A mobile device is not necessary to develop a CE program" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE. I assumed he was doing dev on a local machine.

Comment: He's had several questions recently surrounding development on a device.  His comments to responses on those questions pretty much identified his limitations; guess I just happened to see most of them.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense given that context.